# jquery scrollTop is bouncing

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop

What did I do wrong? My skill bars are dancing. After loading I want to fixed them.

Check my pen here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdEeWW

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
    $('progress').each(function() {
      var max = $(this).val();
      $(this).val(0).animate({
        value: max
      }, {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'easeOutCirc'
      });
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: Dancing means? Like they are changing again and again?

Answer (score 0):

Your `skillbars` were dancing because you have written the `event` on `scroll`. So if you scroll twice before completion of `animation`, then it will begin again and also you are not checking whether your `animation` has been performed.

Just `.stop` the `animation` before animating as below:

```
$(this).stop().val(0).animate({
     value: max
}, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'easeOutCirc'
});
```

**[Fiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ksx7x2pn/)**

---

**Update**

There is a **bug** in the way you are doing it right now. Your original value gets overridden every time you scroll thus giving space for less progress display every time. So what you need to do is, store original value in some `data-*` attribute of each element and set value every time from original value and thus you can also make you `value=0` each time. Below changes will accommodate you with the above effect.

**HTML**

```
<progress value="80" data-originalvalue="80" max="100"></progress>
                   //^^^^To store original value
<span>JavaScript/jQuery</span>
<progress value="70" data-originalvalue="70" max="100"></progress>
<span>HTML5/CSS3</span>
<progress value="60" data-originalvalue="60" max="100"></progress>
<span>NodeJS</span>
<progress value="70" data-originalvalue="70" max="100"></progress>
<span>Java/PHP</span>
<progress value="60" data-originalvalue="60" max="100"></progress>
<span>MySQL</span>
<progress value="80" data-originalvalue="80" max="100"></progress>
<span>Photoshop</span>
```

You **JS** now would be

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
    $('progress').each(function() {
      var max = $(this).data('originalvalue'); //get from data-originalvalue attribute
      $(this).val('0').stop().animate({
        value: max
        }, {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'easeOutCirc'
      });
    });
  };
});
```

**[Updated DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ksx7x2pn/2/)**

Now if you want it to animate only once when it hits users view, you just need to set a global variable value and add one more condition, as below:

```
var isAnimated=false; //global variable

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300 && !isAnimated) {//Also check if animated
    $('progress').each(function() {
      var max = $(this).data('originalvalue');
      $(this).val('0');  
      $(this).stop().animate({
        value: max
        }, {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'easeOutCirc'
      });
    });
    isAnimated=true;//once done set it to true so that animation will not repeat.
  };
});
```

**[One time animation demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ksx7x2pn/3/)**